# How to add header to file in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am storing the header in a CSV file and concatenating it with the data file using mapping data flow.
I am using union Activity to combine these two files. While combining the header file and data file, I can see the data but header data is not at the top. It's randomly present in the sink file.

How can I make the header at top ?

1,Company_Reference_ID,PH2_TIC,USD,PH2_Actuals,2021-03-12,PH2_X_VB_V3,85738,V3Premium
1,Company_Reference_ID,PH2_TIC,USD,PH2_Actuals,2021-03-12,PH2_X_VB_V3,85738,V3Premium
**Journey,CompanyRerenceIDType,CompaReferenceID,Currecy,Ledgerype,Accountinate,Journaource**
1,Company_Reference_ID,PH2_TIC,USD,PH2_Actuals,2021-03-12,PH2_X_VB_V3,85738,V3Commission

Comment: Hi @Shivam Yadav. Kindly let me know if you need more information. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:**
My debug result is as follows, I think it is what you want:
[image]

---

I created a simple test to merge two csv files. One header.csv and another vlaues.csv.
As @Mark Kromer MSFT said we can use  Surrogate Key and then sort these rows.The Row_No of heard.csv will start from `1` and values.csv will start from `2`.

1. Set `header` source to the header.csv and don't select **First row as header**.
   [image]
2. Set `header` source to the values.csv and don't select **First row as header**.
   [image]
3. At `SurrogateKey1` activity , enter `Row_No` as Key column and **`1`** as Start value.
   [image]
4. At `SurrogateKey2` activity , enter `Row_No` as Key column and **`2`** as Start value.
   [image]
5. Then we can uion `SurrogateKey1` stream and `SurrogateKey2` stream at `Union1` activity.
   [image]
6. Then we can sort these rows by `Row_No` at `Sort1` activity.
   [image]
7. We can use `Select1` activity to filter `Row_No` column.
   [image]
8. I think it is what you want:
   [image]

Comment: Very nice, Joseph!  This will work until we release the "Header" property on the sink.

Comment: Hi @Mark Kromer MSFT. We, as users, look forward to your updates to product features to make it more convenient to use. Very thanks!  :)

Answer (score 1):

For now, you would need to use a Surrogate Key for the different streams and make sure that the header row has 1 for the surrogate key value and sort by that column.

We are working on a feature for adding a header to the delimited text sink as a property in the data flow Sink. That will make it much easier and should light-up in the UI soon.